# SharePoint 2010 - SP2

Tags: cumulative-update

Any ideas on when SharePoint 2010 SP2 will release? as our company doesnt want to install CUs.

List of SP CUs and SPs
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this question is a good fit for SharePoint.SE since it can't be definitively answered... IMO, only someone at Microsoft would know for sure when it was going to be released. :)

Comment: And, most likely MS will not share that information right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any announcement about SP2, but my guess would be that I won't be until Microsoft are sure what needs to be patched to be ready to upgrade to SharePoint 15.

So I would not expect it until somewhat after a public beta of SharePoint 15.

Comment: Great. I guess I will have to apply all the CU in date release order and including june SP1.

Comment: You don't need to install all of the **Cumulative** Updates in release order... you only need the latest one. They are cumulative because they include the previous fixes.

Comment: You don't have to install all the CU, the C stands for Cumulative which means that they include everything since the last SP. I'd go for SP1 + December 2011 CU, we're not sure about the February one yet.